# How to volume mariadb container whole file system?

Tags: docker, mariadb

I am running ls command inside the MariaDB container and see a bunch of directories: bin, dev, lib, lib64, tmp, etc.

Tried it, but there are only a few folders

```
/my/own/datadir:/var/lib/mysql
```

How I can volume all container home directory?

Comment: Can you say a little bit more about what you're trying to do?  In normal operation a container gets most of its content from the underlying image, and uses a volume only for things that specifically need to be persisted across deleting and recreating the container (in this case the actual database data).  There's not a "home directory" _per se_ in most cases.

Comment: @DavidMaze I want to find what's going on with the files, in particular with the temporary file, and see how much memory it takes up. Due to the fact that I do not know where exactly this file appears, I wanted to look at the entire file system. In fact, I tried using volume var/lib/mysql which is suggested in the documentation, but I didn't find a temporary file.

Comment: You can't use `volumes:` to republish the container filesystem to the host.  If you just want to look around, a `docker exec` debugging shell will often be an easy tool.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only have to indicate the path as you are doing, in case there are some files you can't see but they are there in the Docker container maybe it's because they are hidden. Try running **ls -la**.

For making a volume of the whole system, then you will have to make a volume per folder in the system. One for /etc one for /var one for /dev as you can't use **/** as a route for the volumes.